# Como passar um arquivo txt para uma parâmetro do tipo Stream?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Como passar um arquivo `txt` para uma parâmetro do tipo Stream?

Essa é a `ActionResult` que chama o método para ler o arquivo `txt`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Incluir(ContaReceberViewModel pContaReceber,
                            HttpPostedFileBase fileRetorno)
{
    try
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileRetorno.FileName);
        var _arquivo = Path
           .Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/Importacao"),
                   fileName); 
        ArquivoRetornoCNAB400 cnab400 = new ArquivoRetornoCNAB400();
        //O erro ocorre aqui, quando tento passar o parâmetro:                
        cnab400.LerArquivoRetorno(bco, new FileStream(_arquivo, FileAccess.Write));
        return View(new ContaReceber());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        TempData["mensagemErro"] = 
          string.Format("Ocorreu um erro ao carregar 
                      tela de importação de arquivos bancários.");
        return View(new ContaReceber());
    }
}
```

Esse é o método que fará a leitura do arquivo txt:

```
public override void LerArquivoRetorno(IBanco banco, Stream arquivo)
{
    try
    {
        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(arquivo, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        string linha = "";

        // Lendo o arquivo
        linha = stream.ReadLine();

        // Próxima linha (DETALHE)
        linha = stream.ReadLine();

        while (DetalheRetorno.PrimeiroCaracter(linha) == "1")
        { 
            DetalheRetorno detalhe = banco.LerDetalheRetornoCNAB400(linha);
            ListaDetalhe.Add(detalhe);
            OnLinhaLida(detalhe, linha);
            linha = stream.ReadLine();
        }

        stream.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Erro ao ler arquivo.", ex);
    }
}
```

***Erro:***

> `The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.FileStream.FileStream(string, System.IO.FileMode)' has some invalid arguments C:\PROJETOS\SistemaBeta.Web\Controllers\ImportaArquivoConciliacaoController.cs  168`

Comment: Não o que está fazendo, talvez passando uma *string*, um arquivo não pode ser passado como parâmetro. Então passe um `Stream`, conforme aprendeu na sua pergunta anterior.

Comment: já tentou utilizando `String` e não `var`?

Comment: bigown eu editei a pergunta para ficar melhor o entendimento, a questão anterior era uma aplicação Console Aplicattion e essa pergunta e uma aplicação Web MVC eu tentei fazer a mesma coisas e dá erro

Comment: Marciano, Andrade eu troquei para String e dá erro: 'The best overloaded method match for 'BoletoNet.AbstractArquivoRetorno.LerArquivoRetorno(BoletoNet.IBanco, System.IO.Stream)' has some invalid arguments'

Comment: Porque você não faz a leitura com o **System.IO.File.ReadAllLines** ?     `string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\arquivo.txt", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
foreach (string line in lines)
{

}`

Comment: Acho que você está complicando sem necessidade. [Esta biblioteca lê e escreve arquivos de layout](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers/).

Comment: Marconcilio Souza como eu passaria essa 'String lines' para o método 'LerArquivoRetorno(IBanco banco, Stream arquivo)', na passagem gera esse erro:  'The best overloaded method match for 'BoletoNet.AbstractArquivoRetorno.LerArquivoRetorno(BoletoNet.IBanco, System.IO.Stream)' has some invalid arguments'

Answer (score 1):

Funcionou usando `using`:

```
using (var fileStream1 = new FileStream(_arquivo, FileMode.Open))
{
    cnab400.LerArquivoRetorno(bco, fileStream1);
}
```